# Grouping and searching the users in Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I want to create different groups in **Azure B2C** like **Department 1**, **Department 2** and assign **employees** for each department. I want to then search for all the employees under each department.

I noticed that **Azure B2C** does not have **Groups**, **Users** and **Roles**. How can I structure the **Azure B2C** to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though out-of-the-box AAD B2C does not expose functionality related to managing Security Groups, the following approach could be considered:

1. use regular AAD portal blade to create groups
2. assign users to groups via Azure AD B2C

Another option would be to introduce `department` as [custom attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#use-a-custom-attribute-in-your-user-flow) of User entity:

1. via Azure AD B2C create a custom attribute or via API: [create a `extensionProperty` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-extensionproperty?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
2. [update user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to save a department claim:

Example:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id-or-upn}
Content-type: application/json

{
  "extension_{b2c-extensions-app-id}_Department": "--department name goes here--"
}
```

where `extension_{b2c-extensions-app-id}_Department` corresponds to department custom attribute [named by using the convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#using-custom-attribute-with-ms-graph-api)  *application (client) ID of the `b2c-extensions-app` without the dashes*

3. and finally retrieve user properties along with department: `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=extension_{b2c-extensions-app-id}_Department`

Comment: (1) Is there a disadvantage or advantage in using *regular AAD* like increae in billing charge? (2) Can a group be created in **regular AAD** programmatically? (3) What would be best choice if there are going to be **50,000 users in a few years**?

Comment: 2) surely, [MS Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-groups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) comes to the rescue 3) good question indeed, not sure but official documentation says the following in this regard: _Azure Active Directory B2C (Azure AD B2C) is a customer identity access management (CIAM) solution capable of supporting millions of users and billions of authentications per day_

Comment: B2C is always cheaper than AAD. Also AAD has a restriction of 5 guest users per AAD account.